# What quarter does a payment on the first of the month belong to?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, payroll-taxes

We pay employees on the first of the month for a pay period from the 26th of two months ago to the 25th of the previous month.  That means the *period worked* and the *paydate* often occur during different quarters.  Which date do we use to determine the quarter for IRS form 941?

For example

1. On Jan 1, we pay for 26 Nov to 25 Dec
2. On Feb 1, we pay for 26 Dec to 25 Jan
3. On Mar 1, we pay for 26 Jan to 25 Feb
4. On Apr 1, we pay for 26 Feb to 25 Mar

When we file a 941 for Q1, do we include line 1 or line 4?

I have heard conflicting answers from two different CPA's on this question.  I am looking for some documentation from the IRS that can settle the issue more clearly.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about corporate income tax, not personal finance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cash accounting (not accrual), the day you pay your employees identifies the corresponding tax period. So the answer to your question is, include line 1, not line 4, assuming you do cash accounting on your taxes.

Likewise, you only deduct taxes in the year you pay them.

http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/payroll-tax-expenses-accrual-methods-13203.html

http://www.irs.gov/publications/p535/ch05.html

http://www.bizfilings.com/toolkit/sbg/tax-info/fed-taxes/tax-consequences-of-compensation.aspx

Comment: The links you provided discuss deducting taxes in the year you pay them.  Do you have any source for cash accounting following the quarter you pay the employee?

Comment: @just.another.programmer: The first link says "The cash method of accounting involves recording each transaction as a sale or an expense when the money changes hands rather than when the sale or purchase is made.  A business that uses the cash method will write off payroll expenses when the payroll checks are written rather than at the end of the pay period [...]"